# Why does my GUI look different when running vs in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, interface, builder

I am using a modal view controller to show a view on screen. I have everything on the view setup and aligned in Interface Builder...
[image: What the view looks like in interface builder]

But when I run my app on my ipad things are not aligned. In the second screenshot there is a gap between the tableview and the dateTimePicker.

[image: How it looks on the iPad]

In interface builder I have the view size set as 540x620 which is the size of the modal view. Any ideas why it looks differently when I run my app?

Edit: Here's how I present the view

```
// Create the variable that represents the app delegate
KMAppDelegate *delegate = (KMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Create view controller
ModalDetailVC *modalDetailVC = [[ModalDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalDetailVC" bundle:nil];

// Call the pushViewController:animated method from the navigationController variable inside the delegate
[delegate.navigationController pushViewController:modalDetailVC animated:YES];

modalDetailVC.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 620);
modalDetailVC.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

Comment: How are you presenting it modally? What autoresizing masks does your views have?

Comment: I have edited my post to show how I present the view.

Comment: You are not presenting it modally, you are pushing it inside a navigation controller. The reason that the picker looks of probably has to do with missing autoresizing masks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the autoresizing mask for the date picker in interface builder to this [image: Autoresizing mask]

Thanks for the help.